# Vuejs bind object to object if

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

My calendar creates 41 days with the help of moment.

```
    for (let x = 0; x < 42; x++) {
        context.add(1, 'd');
        let day = {
            'date': moment(context),
            'events': []
        };
    }
    state.month = days;
```

I then render the days.

```
        <day
             v-for="(day, index) in days"
             v-bind:day="day"
             v-bind:index="index"
             v-bind:key="day.id">
            0
        </day>
```

I collect day events per month from the database and send them to vue.

```
**Event**
id
name
date
is_accepted

public static function getEventsByMonth($month) {
    return Events::whereMonth('date', '=', $month);
}
```

Now for the main question: Is there a vue way to properly bind events to days ? Or will I have to loop each event in each day comparing dates?

Edit:

Events in my vuestore after getting them from the database:

```
events:Object
2017-04-02 00:00:00:Object
2017-04-14 00:00:00:Object
```

And here are the days:

```
days:Array[42]
0:Object
1:Object
```

Comment: Question 1 : you can't change your php code ? Question 2 : `events:Object` contains all events but what it happens when there is 2 events the same day ?

Comment: I can change everything. Its impossible to have 2 events on the same day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array in back-end when you get events from database (change to your need) :

```
$events = array();

foreach( $eventsFromDatabase as $event) {//$event is the event get from database
    if( !isset($event[$date]) ) {
        $events[$date] = array();
    }
    $events[$date][] = $events;
} 

return json_encode($events);
```

And then in Vue :

```
<day
    v-for="(day, index) in days"
    v-bind:day="day"
    v-bind:index="index"
    v-bind:key="day.id">

   <!-- You must create the event component -->
   <event v-for="(event, index) in events[day]" :key="event"
          :id="event.id" :name="event.name" :date="event.date"
          :is-accepted="event['is_accepted']
          >
       
   </event>

</day>
```

### UPDATED :

The logic is : for each `day`, you put event inside the day component if event existed :

```
<day v-for...> HERE PUT EVENT COMPONENT </day>
```

In the definition of `day` component template you should use `<slot></slot>` to accept html from parent : [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots).

Because you loop trough `days` array you can access the value of the day (don't know the key for date of moment.js, like day.date for example) and then you can access to the right event with :

```
events[day.date] // change the .date to your needs (for moment.js)
```

So you can access to the event name like this :

```
<day v-for="(day, index) in days"...>
    <div v-if="events[day.date] !== 'undefined'">
        <event :name="events[day.date].name ...etc..></event>
    <di>
</day>
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but I think this assumes that a day knows it has an event. This is not the case.

Comment: @Macdows No I don't assume a day knows it has event. You create (in PHP) an events array with day as key. Then in Vue you do the 2nd loop with `events[day]` but day don't knows it has event. This is events array who knows events with the day key.

Comment: @Macdows Please put your PHP code that get events from database. In PHP, the `date` for `Event` is a month or a full date (day, month and year) ?

Comment: I updated the OP with days and events data in the vue store.

Comment: Could you instead of pasting code maybe just tell me what the goal is? At what point will the day component render the event component? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help but this just renders which I already knew. Sorry if I worded my question wrong.